# What is the relationship between an executor and an io_context in boost asio?

Tags: boost-asio, executor

Given the code below:

```
  boost::asio::io_context io_ctxt;
  boost::asio::thread_pool pool;

  tcp::acceptor a1( io_ctxt.get_executor(),tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),1313));
  tcp::acceptor a2( pool.get_executor(),tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),1414));

//... call async_accept on both acceptors

  io_ctxt.run();
```

is a2 even active (since pool is in no way associated to the io_context)?
At a more general level, is there anywhere a set of requirements on the relation between an executor and an io_context?

Thank you